# Elasticsearch facet value for an id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

im using elasticsearch on rails with Tire.

My code:

```
def to_indexed_json
    {
      :id                 => id,  
      :brand_name         => brand_name,
      :brand_id           => brand_id
    }.to_json
end

facet "brands" do
  terms :brand_id
end
```

I have to query on database to retrieve the name of all brands returned by elasticsearch. Is there a way to return these values (brand_name) from elasticsearch?

Comment: Why is your facet on brand_id and not on brand_name? Wouldn't that would solve your problem?

Comment: because when user clicks on the desired brand, i pass the selected brand through the url. I would rather pass the id instead of the brand_name.

Comment: I see... I don't think you can get the brand_name within the facet results. I hope I'm wrong. I had the same "problem", but I just passed the brand (event in my case) name in the url (...&event=eventname...)

Comment: You could use a facet based on a `script_field` composed of both id and name. Then on the frontend you need to somehow strip the id out of the facet entry in order to show only the name, but you can keep the key to apply the filter when a user selects the entry itself. Does it sound good?

Comment: @javanna hmm i liked it! If there is no other way i think im gonna stick with you approach. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, I'm gonna add my solution as an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a facet based on the id field combined with a script which adds the name to each entry, so that each entry will be then composed of both id and name:

```
"facets" : {
    "tag" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "id",
            "script" : "term + \"_\" + _source.name"
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the frontend you need to somehow strip the id out of the facet entry in order to show only the name (I hope your id cannot contain a `_`), but you can keep the key to apply the filter when a user selects the entry itself.